# Разный результат считывания файла

Tags: c, файлы

считываю файл на компютере (Убунту "механизированный бабёр")

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("TYT!\n");
    FILE *fp;
    char ch; // делал по герберту шилду говорят надо int из за того 
             // что getc() возвращает интовый результат
    if ((fp = fopen("/home/comp/untitled10/test", "r"))==NULL){
        printf("Невозможно открыть файл.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    ch = getc(fp);

    while(ch!=EOF)
    {
        putchar(ch);
        ch = getc(fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Всё ОК.

Считываю файл на другом компьютере (Debian 9), код тот-же.
Отличие имеет только файл который считывается `/sys/class/leds/STATUS_GREEN/brightness`

При работе программы возникает ошибка : `Segmentation fault`

Пропробывал просто считать только один символ,  но увы такая же ошибка `Segmentation fault`

```
ch = getc(fp);
putchar(ch);
```

Не знаю что делать.

Comment: В любом случае, раз уж вы сравниваете `ch != EOF`, этот `ch` надо делать `int ch;`.

Comment: @Harry  это не я так придумал а Герберт Шилдт

Comment: Ну вам  же уже, наверное, раз сто объясняли, что книги Герберта Шилдта - макулатура, битком набитая такими ошибками?

Comment: @AnT вы первый :3 ни разу про его книги мне не кто плохого не сказал. Даже больше скажу это книги с которых я начал "стучать по клавиатуре"

Comment: Странно. Шилдт в программистских кругах - это фактически "мем" некачественно написанных книг. И если какие-то мысли из них еще можно спасти, то код - это просто собрание ошибок. Когда-то его книги громили на accu.org, но с тех пор много воды утекло...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Linux, в каталоге `sys` живут не полноценные файлы, а проекция параметров/настроек ядра системы в файловом эквиваленте, они могут легко не иметь EOF, и не поддерживать операцию `seek` в некоторых случаях, так-же некоторые файлы в этой системе не поддерживают операцию чтения, только запись.

Конкретно по каждому виртуальному файлу надо смотреть спецификацию ядра, какие есть возможности работы с этим файлом и как там располагается информация.

Упрощённо, это виртуальные файлы ссылающиеся на область памяти.

> /sys - это виртуальная файловая система, к которой можно получить
>   доступ для установки или получения информации о представлении системы
>   ядром.
>   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview

Документация по виртуальной файловой системе `sys` применительно к программированию на `C/C++`: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt